# iReport : How to add a group after another (not inside)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, ireport

normally iReports creates group like this:

---

### Group 1 Header

### Group 2 Header

### Detail

### Group 2 Footer

### Group 1 Footer

But I need the goups to be created this way:

---

### Group 1 Header

### Detail

### Group 1 Footer

---

### Group 2 Header

### Detail

### Group 2 Footer

How can I get this to work the way that I need?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get this working is having a subreport with which holds group 2.

Main report:

- group expression for `group1`, add group header and footer band
- sub report in e.g. summary band

Sub report:

- group expression for `group2`, add group header and footer band

Comment: Really Thanks!!! one more help, does I need to manage both report and sub report separately in JAVA??